# How to change textSize of Context Menu in Android

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to change the text size of Context Menu in Android, can anyone give me the simplest solution for that problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try create value of context menu in string.xml instead of in context_menu.xml